# Start multiple processes with one action

Tags: qgis, actions

I am trying to start multiple processes with a single action in QGIS.

With Windows commands it is not hard, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719174/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-a-single-line

But a simple try inside Qgis like this

calc.exe | notepad.exe

Does not work and only calc.exe is started.

Neither of the following options works.

generic, python, mac, windows, unix, open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to start commands asynchroneously with `calc.exe & notepad.exe`, but I am not sure this works on Windows and maybe even on unixoid systems this will need to be wrapped like `bash -c 'calc.exe & notepad.exe'` or similar.

What should work though is using python for this

```
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('calc.exe')
Popen('notepad.exe')
```

Or write a simple batch script to call (.bat).

Comment: amazing 'subprocess import Popen' work very good